# getRangeByName('namedRange') only works on ActiveSheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy");
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("CUSTOMER_EMAILS");
var SheetDataRange = ws.getRangeByName("rngRangeName");
```

Why does this getRangeByName doesn't work on this type of sheet name access, it only works if I have the ActiveSheet object? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Not so. It'll work on any sheet. What made you jump to such a conclusion?

Comment: This works for me`function getData() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const vs=tss.getRangeByName("NamedRange1").getValues();
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Named ranges are set on the Spreadsheet, not on a Sheet.

As such, `getRangeByName()` is a function on the `Spreadsheet` class. You don't/can't call it against a sheet.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy");
var SheetDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("rngRangeName");
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. It works by accessing the Spreadsheet.